# What is the name for the topology where every point forms an open set

Tags: general-topology, terminology

I remember there is some name for a    special topology on a set, such that    every subset is open i.e. every point    forms an open set, but I cannot    recall it.

Please tell me its name or say I am    wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe it is called the [Discrete Topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_topology).